# How come "tales" can get 'taller' as in “his tales are getting taller”?

Tags: adjectives

> “You are merely repeating the names of those who were acquitted of being Death Eaters thirteen years ago!” said Fudge angrily. “You could have found those names in old reports of the trials! For heavens sake, Dumbledore - the boy was full of some crackpot story at the end of last year too - **his tales are getting taller**, and you're still swallowing them - the boy can talk to snakes. Dumbledore, and you still think he's trustworthy?”
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*</sub>

I'm just wondering how come '*tales*' can get '*taller*'? It seems to me that tales are getting **longer** makes more sense. How should we understand it here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [tall tale](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tall_tale) is an exaggerated, fantastic story (Wiktionary)